# How can I show $\omega + \omega^2 = \omega^2$, regarding $\omega$ as an ordinal?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I believe $\omega + \omega^2 = \omega^2$, and it may be possible to show this in a messy fashion using the definitions of ordinal arithmetic, however I believe there exists a short and elegant way to equate these two ordinals.

Comment: What is the messy fashion? $\omega^2$ is the result of concatenating $\omega$ copies of $\omega$. $\omega+\omega^2$ is the same thing.

Comment: Probably the messy fashion is $\omega+\omega^2 = \omega (1+\omega) = \omega\omega= \omega^2$

Comment: @Andrés: I imagine the messy way is to unravel the recursive definitions.

Comment: @Max this is actually the answer I was looking for, and is a rather fast way. I wasn't aware that ordinal multiplication was left distributive. What Asaf suggested is correct- I was trying to avoid the recursive definitions. Thanks!